# Active Reports not showing sub reports in exported pdf

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, activereports

I am using Active Reports (Evaluation version) and developed a report in my C# application, I have one main report and one sub-report in the details section of main report

I have done coding according to the Active reports documentation [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/EmbedSubreportsAndPassParameters.html)

I can see the desired result in the preview section but after exporting the report to PDF file It dose not render the sub-report.

Can any one help me with this? Thanks in advance

Below is the code of my main report

```
    using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace Abc.XQ.Reports.Reports
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for TestSubReport.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestSubReport : GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport
    {


        public TestSubReport()
        {
            //
            // Required for Windows Form Designer support
            //
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pageHeader_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private SubReport rpt1;

        private void TestSubReport_ReportStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rpt1 = new SubReport();
            rpt1.LoadLayout(XmlReader.Create(@"E:\Projects\Restarted\New folder\Sample reports\SubReport2.rpx"));
        }

        private void TestSubReport_FetchData(object sender, FetchEventArgs eArgs)
        {

        }

        private void detail_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.sub1.Report = rpt1;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the API controller which calls my main report and generates the the PDF

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("testSub")]
    public void GetSubReport()
    {
        TestSubReport rpt = new TestSubReport();
        XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\MyPDF\mMyPDF1.rpx", null);
        rpt.Run();
        try
        {
            rpt.SaveLayout(xtw);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            xtw.Close();
        }

        TestSubReport report1 = new TestSubReport();
        report1.LoadLayout(new XmlTextReader(@"C:\MyPDF\mMyPDF1.rpx"));

        report1.FetchData += (sender, args) =>
        {                   args.EOF = true;
        };

        report1.DataInitialize += (sender, args) =>
        {
        };



        report1.Run();
        var pdfExport = new PdfExport();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        pdfExport.Export(report1.Document, stream);

        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=myRreport.pdf");
        response.Buffer = true;
        stream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
        response.End();
    }
```

Comment: since this a web application, have you checked if the path to the report is accessible at runtime "E:...".

Comment: Yes,  I have checked that,  it is accessible

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with the help of Grape City support
just commented the following lines of code and it stared working

```
report1.LoadLayout(new XmlTextReader(@"C:\MyPDF\mMyPDF1.rpx"));

    report1.FetchData += (sender, args) =>
    {                   args.EOF = true;
    };

    report1.DataInitialize += (sender, args) =>
    {
    };
```